# ActionBarSherlock v3.4.2 build errors

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I've added ActionBarSherlock to an Android project in IntelliJ IDEA, and I'm seeing the following build errors

Everything in the IDE says I'm building against platform API 11, which I expected would include these styles, though looking in API 11 I can't see them.

What am I missing? Does ABS only work with a later Android platform version?

```
Information:Compilation completed with 6 errors and 0 warnings
Information:6 errors
Information:0 warnings
C:\Users\Ollie\Documents\Dropbox\Tech\Blah\ActionBarSherlock\res\values-v13\abs__styles.xml
    Error:Error:line (4)C:\Users\Ollie\Documents\Dropbox\Tech\Blah\ActionBarSherlock\res\values-v13\abs__styles.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabBar'.
    Error:Error:line (5)C:\Users\Ollie\Documents\Dropbox\Tech\Blah\ActionBarSherlock\res\values-v13\abs__styles.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView'.
    Error:Error:line (6)C:\Users\Ollie\Documents\Dropbox\Tech\Blah\ActionBarSherlock\res\values-v13\abs__styles.xml:6: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText'.
    Error:Error:line (8)C:\Users\Ollie\Documents\Dropbox\Tech\Blah\ActionBarSherlock\res\values-v13\abs__styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar'.
    Error:Error:line (9)C:\Users\Ollie\Documents\Dropbox\Tech\Blah\ActionBarSherlock\res\values-v13\abs__styles.xml:9: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
    Error:Error:line (10)C:\Users\Ollie\Documents\Dropbox\Tech\Blah\ActionBarSherlock\res\values-v13\abs__styles.xml:10: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
```

Relevant source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
    <style name="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabBar"></style>
    <style name="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabView" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView"></style>
    <style name="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabText" parent="android:Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText"></style>

<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabBar" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabBar"></style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabView" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView"></style>
<style name="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabText" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText"></style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Int the manifest there is a target version 13. use it.
below the manifest of a library.

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="4"
        android:targetSdkVersion="13" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: Yes, I just noticed Jake says "The library itself must be built against Android 3.2 (API level 13). Your project should be built using the latest version of the SDK as possible (it is best to try and use the same version as the library). This is not a requirement, however, and you may build against any version of the SDK that is Android 3.0 (API level 11) or newer."

Comment: ...and (currently at least) below 14 ;)